# Excluding projects in MSBuild CLI

Tags: .net, visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild

I'm trying to automate a **.Net** console application build from **Jenkins** using **MSBuild** plugin. There are a total of 36 projects present in the solution when I'm using **Visual Studio** 4 projects are showing unloaded and build was successful. But when I try to build it using **MSBuild**, **MSBuild** tries to load these unloaded projects and fails. I have used configuration which does not contain these projects still **MSBuild** tries to build it. 32 projects are written n `C#` and remaining are in `C++`. Is there any way to exclude these projects and build them.

Comment: create a new solution file that only has those?

Comment: Is there any workaround from jenkins. I would like to fix it from DevOps side. is it possible

Comment: It didnt't went well. I tried to resolve the issue by troubleshooting the failed projects. And it worked.

Comment: @AfnanAshraf, it sounds like you have a workaround about your issue, if so, you could `add an answer about it here` which could help us understand this issue:)

Answer (score 1):

> Excluding projects in MSBuild CLI

I think you should write a custom build script to remove those projects based on your requirements.

**For an example**,

create a file called `test.csproj` and then add these in it:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <MyProjectReferences Include="**\*.*proj" />
    <MyProjectReferences Remove="xxx\xxxx.vcxproj;xxx\vxproj;test.csproj" /> //add any projects here you want to exclude 
  </ItemGroup>



  <Target Name="BuildProject">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProjectReferences)" Targets="Build" />
  </Target>

 <Target Name="CleanProject">
 <MSBuild Projects="@(MyProjectReferences)" Targets="Clean" />
</Target>

</Project>
```

**Note**: You should also remove `test.csproj` because `**\*.*proj` already contains it and you should remove it to avoid getting into an endless loop.

**Then**, upload the `test.csproj` file into **Jenkins** and please put the file on the `solution folder` on **Jenkins**。

**Also** remember to check the relative path in the `test.csproj` file again to make sure you can find all the items based on the current cloud address.

==============================

**When** you use **MSBuild.exe** to build project in Jenkins, please set **MSBuild Build File** to `test.csproj`

then set **Command Line Arguments** to

```
-t:BuildProject -p:Configuration=Debug xxxxxx
```

**Besides**, it is the same on Azure Devops, you should instead use MSBuild Task and then specify the `test.csproj` file to get what you want.